# FTP a file from a Server's Subfolder using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, ftp

I'm trying to get a file from a Windows Server to our Oracle Application Server directory named `EXT_TAB_DATA`.
I have followed the sample of a similar SO post ([PL/SQL FTP API binary vs ascii mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780279/pl-sql-ftp-api-binary-vs-ascii-mode)), using [Tim Hall's FTP Package](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ftp-from-plsql.).

**Code Block**

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  l_conn  UTL_TCP.connection;
BEGIN

  L_CONN := FTP.login (p_host    => 'sample.corp.server'   -- this is a sample, not the real IP address
                       p_user    => 'corporate/user1', -- this is a sample, not the real User
                       p_port    => '21',
                       p_pass    => 'pwd');

  ftp.binary(p_conn => l_conn);  

  ftp.get (p_conn       => l_conn,
           p_from_file  => '101_Test.csv',
           p_to_dir     => 'EXT_TAB_DATA',
           p_to_file    => '101_Test_Trans.csv');

  ftp.logout(l_conn);

END;
/
```

However, the file i'm trying to transfer is located in a subfolder named "Payroll_Folder" in "sample.corp.server.
Seems `FTP.login` only checks the main directory of the host, and not inside subfolders.

How can I get the the file '101_Test.csv' from the Server/Directory "sample.corp.server/Payroll_Folder"?

Comment: @EdHeal, you are awesome, kindly state it as an answer and i'll accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
p_from_file => '101_Test.csv'
```

to

```
p_from_file => 'Payroll_Folder/101_Test.csv'
```